# choose a link with 2 parameters using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div>
    <p>
        <a class="article-link" href="/title1">Title 1</a>
        <a class="article-link" href="/title1">year1</a>
    </p>
    <p>
        <a class="article-link" href="/title2">Title 3</a>
        <a class="article-link" href="/title2">year2</a>
    </p>
    <p>
        <a class="name-link" href="/title3">Title 3</a>
        <a class="name-link" href="/title3">year1</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

I need to automate some function in a website. I want to redirect to the link, if you know the title AND the year, using javascript.
for example: I want to be redirected to the link of title3 and year1.
I tried with this:

```
function picktitle() {
  chrome.storage.sync.get('title', function(data) {
      var items = document.getElementsByClassName('article-link');

      for(i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if((items[i].innerHTML).includes(title)) {
          chrome.runtime.sendMessage({redirect: items[i].href});
          break;
        }
      }
  });
}
```

but it choose only the first parameter and i need that it choose the href based on both title and year.
I hope I explained myself.

Comment: Don't [delete questions with a comment history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66900595/choose-between-2-html-parameters-with-javascript?noredirect=1) and start again. **Edit** them to make them clear.

Comment: Are you making a chrome extension?

Comment: yes evolutionxbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm really sorry if im misunderstanding this, but wouldn't using the `&&` keyword in your if statement be the solution? For example:

```
if (statement1 && statement2) // only runs if both statement1 AND statement2 are true
    // do stuff
```

Also, maybe select the parent element and check to see if it's children have two elements with the required text properties:

```
function picktitle() {
  chrome.storage.sync.get('title', function(data) {
      var items = document.getElementsByClassName('article-link');
   
      for(i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        if(
          // Checks if the parent contains the title and the year
          (items[i].parentElement.innerText).includes(title) &&
          (items[i].parentElement.innerText).includes(year)) {
              
          chrome.runtime.sendMessage({redirect: items[i].href});
          break;
        }
      }
  });
}
```

I also changed `innerHTML` to `innerText` because you probably don't need all the html code with it too.

Comment: it doesn't do what I want, but you gave me the inspiration and i did it. However thank you.